# "Failed to check receipt hash" after switching to a new computer?

Tags: macos, applications, mac-appstore

I just had to move my drives over to another Mac Pro and now when I attempt to open apps purchased from the App Store, I'm getting `Failed to check receipt hash`.  What does one need to do in order to revalidate a machine properly for the App Store so that these errors go away?

Comment: see this Q&A for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943183/a-complete-solution-to-locally-validate-an-in-app-receipts-and-bundle-receipts-o

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to redownload those apps from the App Store in order to get new receipts that match your new Mac.